# My Flask Api tries to get form data, but it is not building a Dict correctly

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

I have an object i create on the front end:

```
var data = {id:1, type:13, name:"foo", isReadonly: True};
$.ajax({
  method: "post",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: {filename:f, json:data}
});
```

When I get to my python I have as follows:

```
class Process(Resource):
  def get(self):
    pass

  def post(self):
    data = request.form.to_dict()
    print "Raw: %s" % data
    print "Filename: %s" % data["filename"]
    print "Dataset: %s" % data["json"]
    return data["json"]

api.add_resource(Process, "/process")
```

When looking at the result for dataset, it changed around my keys.  So now I get:

```
"json[id]" : 1
```

Ideally, im trying to turn this into a json object I can reference.. but i will get a key error if i try to do:  data["json"]  because *json* doesnt exist, so it will throw an exception.

I also tried:  `data = request.get_json()` and `data = request.get_json(force=True)` and those dont seem to work either.

How can i set a variable to my json map so i can pass it into followon functions?  I feel it just isnt parsed correctly, or isnt doing a deep parse.

*Edit*  I tried to stringify the data as well, and do request.get_json() but it will return none if i try to print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need stringify the data and use get_json().
A mini work example:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var data = {id:1, type:13, name:"foo", isReadonly: true};
    var f = "hello.py";
    var url = "/hello"
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "post",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({filename:f, json:data}),
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    with open('index.html') as fp:
        return fp.read()


@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    data = request.get_json()
    print("Raw: %s" % data)
    print("Filename: %s" % data["filename"])
    print("Dataset: %s" % data["json"])
    return jsonify(data["json"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

run and visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/:

```
$ python app.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2017 20:38:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Raw: {'json': {'type': 13, 'name': 'foo', 'isReadonly': True, 'id': 1}, 'filename': 'hello.py'}
Filename: hello.py
Dataset: {'type': 13, 'name': 'foo', 'isReadonly': True, 'id': 1}
127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2017 20:38:22] "POST /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: ill test this quick

Comment: This doesnt seem to work.  I made your adjustments, and when trying to print out Data, it just says: None.

Comment: @Fallenreaper How about the new ajax code? I already updated it.

Comment: I removed Stringify and kept get_json in place, that still sets `data` to None though.  request is defined as: `from Flask import request` just in case there is a different module for the request object.

Comment: do you have a working sample?  Maybe there is something minor you are overlooking?

Comment: I got it working, I shifted from the endpoint being an api_resource back to just flask.  It seemed that the errors i was getting was that i didnt do jsonify from within your example.  Now it works, thanks!